# Ubuntu 11.04 Unity / Classic load fails - remains at background without toolbars / windows

Tags: boot, login, 11.04, amd-graphics

IMPORTANT: Ubuntu Classic (without effects) works. I am trying to get Unity to work.

I have the following problem with Ubuntu 11.04 (had it with 10.10 too, but disabling KMS or using the `fglrx` driver fixed it - can't remember exactly which), but now since the Radeon driver is better than it used to be, I want to use it (not to mention the `fglrx` performance is disappointing).

Ubuntu boots normally until the login screen. After login, it shows the background, the mouse is shown and it just remains there. It does not freeze, but it does not load anything else. I can move the mouse and can go into text console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>).

It does not work on Ubuntu profile (Unity) or on the Ubuntu Classic (GNOME + effects) profile. I even tried installing GNOME3 from their PPA, but it does not finish loading either (just like the other two).

My hardware: Toshiba Satellite M40 Notebook, ATI Radeon x600 (128MB) video card

I haven't been able to find any errors in `dmesg` or other logs.

Update 1:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> does not work -- nothing pops up.
There is a GNOME panel loaded (I see the process in the text console) when trying Ubuntu Classic (with effects). Even the Unity panel service loads when I use the Ubuntu profile. I get the impression that something doesn't finish loading (in both Ubuntu and Classic with effects) because if I move the mouse over to where the toolbar would be I get the working mouse.

The thing is with `fglrx` I get an error when trying to load Unity, saying to use Classic because of a lack of hardware. But with the Radeon driver, I don't get that error, they seem to start loading but never finish -- they just hang.

It would be nice if the Radeon driver would allow me to use effects/unity/GNOME 3 since Unity seems to run well on an Intel 945m Express integrated video card notebook. I hope updates to the driver/Unity will fix my problem.

```
$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p

OpenGL vendor string: X.Org R300 Project
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on ATI RV380
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 7.10.2
Not software rendered: yes
Not blacklisted: yes
GLX fbconfig: yes
GLX texture from pixmap: yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program: yes
GL fragment program: yes
GL vertex buffer object: yes
GL framebuffer object: yes
GL version is 1.4+: yes
Unity supported: yes
```

The Unity script says that I should be running Unity.

I found lots of bugs related to this (I think) like [Ubuntu bug 777341](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/777341) and [Ubuntu bug 758482](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/758482) and lots of questions relating to it here in Ask Ubuntu and on other sites. I will assume that this is a problem that will be resolved in future Ubuntu updates.

Update 2:

Fiddling with Compiz plugins (Gnome Plugin or Unity Plugin) in CCSM does not help.

The same goes for uninstalling Compiz/Unity and reinstalling it.

I am starting to get the feeling that this is not an easy thing to fix, and only a driver (Radeon/r300g/Gallium)/Compiz/Unity Ubuntu update will fix this.

Answer (score 4):

Change the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` in:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.modeset=1 pci=nomsi"
```

Run `update-grub` and reboot

The `pci=nomsi` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Second Attempt**
Go to a command line <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.
Create this folder:

```
mkdir  ~/.config/autostart
```

Create this file:

```
nano ~/.config/autostart/gnome.desktop
```

Paste this into it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=gnome-panel
Name[en_US]=Gnome
Exec=gnome-panel
Name=Gnome
Icon=gnome-panel
```

Then

```
sudo reboot now
```

**First Attempt**
I needed to put `gnome-panel` as a command at Startup Applications (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and paste`gnome-session-properties`) to fix something like this. Can you test it?

Comment: Alt+F2 does not work. Nothing pops up.

Comment: I've edited the answer. Hope this can fix.

Comment: Second attempt doesn't do the trick either. Even without your modification there is a gnome panel loaded (i see the process in the text console). Even the unity panel service loads when I use the Ubuntu profile. I get the impression that something doesn't finish loading (in both Ubuntu and classic with effects) because if I move the mouse over to where the toolbar would be I get the working mouse. I just tried entering Ubuntu Classic (without effects) and it worked.

Comment: Th ething is with fglrx I get n error when trying to load unity, saying to use classic because of lack of hardware. But with the radeon driver I don't get that error, they seem to start loading but never end. They just hang.

Comment: I will look toward a solution and post here if I find something.

Comment: Entering Ubuntu Classic without effects, can you do the "First Attempt" then try to enter again?

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me, you can do this to fix:

Go to Ubuntu Classic (without effects), start CCSM and enable Gnome Plugin or Unity Plugin.

Seems that Compiz has some problem to use them both, because the plugins seem to conflict.

Comment: Sorry, but in my CCSM only Gnome Plugin is enabled, Unity Plugin is not enabled. I tried "compiz --replace" and got to the freezing part. I also disabled Gnome Plugin and tried unity and got to the same old "freezing". Thanx anyway.

Answer (score -1):

the same thing happened to me and i think i have your solution
(or at least this is what work for me)

boot up in **Ubuntu classi**c and go to **system - administration - synaptic package manager**
remove anything that has to do with compiz (or anything that has compiz in the name)

now restart your computer and boot up in **Ubuntu** and press **ctrl alt t** and your **terminal** should come up type in this line **sudo apt-get install compiz** then press enter after that type in this line **sudo apt-get install unity** press enter then **sudo apt-get upgrade unity**

after its done restart your computer and boot in to **ubuntu** and bam everything is back

Comment: Sorry, that did not work, i don't think that the packages were corrupted / not correctly installed. I had the exact same "freeze". Thanx anyway.