# Unity/gnome mess

Tags: gnome, unity-2d, globalmenu

I've recently upgraded from 10.10 to 11.04, and immediately switched to unity-2d (running on a netbook). Then I tried to load the 10.10 panels because I didn't like the globalmenu. After rebooting I ended up w/out Unity and w/out Gnome. Alt+F2 doesn't open terminal either, and I can only access the browser thanks to a keyboard shortcut I once set up. How do I resolve this mess..? When I logout/login it doesn't let me choose between settings (ubuntu classic, etc.).

Thanks!

Comment: Boot into the recovery mode, choose *Drop to root shell prompt*, then do `nano /home/YOURUSER/.dmrc` and change the Session entry to *Session=gnome-2d*. Press Ctrl + o, Enter, Ctrl + x. Now run `chown YOURUSER:YOURUSER /home/YOURUSER/.dmrc` and reboot. You now should at least boot into a classic GNOME session.

Answer (score 1):

While not necessarily a solution to your dilemma, **ATL-F2** should let you run anything.  Does **CTRL-ALT-T** bring up a terminal window for you?  Are you trying to run Unity with the addition of a Gnome-Panel at the bottom, or are you attempting to run the classic Gnome interface on your netbook?

Comment: htorque: I'm totally new to all of this. How do I book into the recovery mode, and where would I choose "drop to shell prompt"? Sorry, but it's getting a bit confusing from that point on....

Kory Wnuk: cntrl+alt+t doesn't work either. And I don't care much for unity any more ... I'd be happy with a simple classic Gnome interface.

also, I'd like to add that the symptoms are similar to those reported here:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/40426/ubuntu-11-04-unity-classic-load-fails-remains-at-background-without-toolbars
although I couldn't figure out if any answer there provides a solution

Comment: the answere here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/40426/ubuntu-11-04-unity-classic-load-fails-remains-at-background-without-toolbars/40430#40430 solved the problem. at least temporarily. Thanks.